# How to populate Parameter in $cordovaSQLite as my own array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I used this codes to execute `$cordovaSQLite` insert.

```
var qst_master_content_data= {
                             qst_cnt_id :content.qst_cnt_id,
                             question_id :content.question_id,
                             qst_cnt_text :content.qst_cnt_text,
                             qst_cnt_options :content.qst_cnt_options,
                             qst_story:content.qst_story,
                             explanation :content.explanation,
                             lang_id :content.lang_id,
                             img_id :content.img_id,
                             dt_update :content.dt_update

                         };
var query = "INSERT INTO qst_master_content ( "+
                                "qst_cnt_id, "+
                                "question_id, "+
                                "qst_cnt_text, "+
                                "qst_cnt_options, "+
                                "qst_story, "+
                                "explanation, "+
                                "lang_id, "+
                                "img_id, "+
                                "dt_update "+
                                ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, qst_master_content_data).then(function(res)
                    {
                        console.log(res);
                    },
                    function(err)
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
```

Unfortunately the insert was not successfully inserted.
I was tried to use `qst_master_cotent = [1,2,3];` then it would be ok.
But this not make my codes to be reuse on that format. It should be:

```
var qst_master_content_data= {
                             qst_cnt_id :content.qst_cnt_id,
                             question_id :content.question_id,
                             qst_cnt_text :content.qst_cnt_text,
                             qst_cnt_options :content.qst_cnt_options,
                             qst_story:content.qst_story,
                             explanation :content.explanation,
                             lang_id :content.lang_id,
                             img_id :content.img_id,
                             dt_update :content.dt_update

                         };
```

So that I can manipulate the data in the future. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull about variable names. Your parameter object name is qst_master_cotent.
It should be like this:

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, qst_master_cotent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code

```
       var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
                name: "your.db"
            });
            db.transaction(populateClientDB, error, success);

        function populateClientDB(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO qst_master_content (qst_cnt_id, question_id, qst_cnt_text, qst_cnt_options, qst_story, explanation, lang_id, img_id, dt_update) \n\
                     VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", [qst_master_cotent.qst_cnt_id, qst_master_cotent.question_id, qst_master_cotent.qst_cnt_text, qst_master_cotent.qst_cnt_options, qst_master_cotent.qst_story, qst_master_cotent.explanation, qst_master_cotent.lang_id, qst_master_cotent.img_id, qst_master_cotent.dt_update], function(tx, res) {
                console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
                console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");
            });
        }

        function error(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        function success() {

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: I knew that way, what I meant was I want the my own array as in the question.

Comment: maybe , You are getting problem because its (key,value) pair object

Comment: Yes, but is that only way on parameter array like [1,2,3,..] ?

Comment: Your problem is suggesting , It is . Let me try

Comment: bydway you are using object not array :)

Comment: Owh...how to write in array with (key,value)?